# How to configure Apache Kafka broker port in server.properties file

Tags: apache-kafka

While creating the producer I have to specify the broker port value.

For that, I need to configure that broker port value in 'server.properties' file.

What are these 'listeners' and 'advertised.listeners' parameters,
and how can I configure them as broker port?

If broker port value is a mandatory, then why these parameters have commented?

If these parameters are automatically initializing from 'java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()',  then how can I specify those automatically initialized port values while creating a new producer?

Thanks.

```
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not set `advertised.listeners`, it is the same as `listeners` by default.

`listeners` are used in the inside network IP, `advertised.listeners` are used in the outside network IP. If you only need to use Kafka in the inside, you only need to configure `listeners`.

`listeners` are the parameters that the socketserver actually bind(). `advertised.listeners` will stored in zk.

In inside Network, you can use the 192.168.0.10 to connected Kafka Broker.By outside network, so you should be config the `advertised.listeners`

```
# inside network IP, like that
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.10:9092

# Public network ip, so you can connect the broker in any network
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092
```

Other:
The format of the parameter value is (protocol name)://(host name or ip):(port number)

protocol name `PLAINTEXT` means clear text transmission,

protocol name `SSL` means using SSL or TLS encrypted transmission, etc.

Comment: Wtf is an "inside" or "outside" network?

Answer (score 1):

> why these parameters have commented?

As the comments say, they have defaults

> If these parameters are automatically initializing from 'java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()', then how can I specify those automatically initialized port values while creating a new producer?

Default port is 9092, so you'd connect to that ip/hostname on port 9092.

> What are these 'listeners' and 'advertised.listeners' parameters

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/